# Can't load custom font on website

Tags: css, web, fonts, font-face

I'm using @font-face to try and load a custom font on my website, at least on google chrome.

Still, I'm having a hard time doing so... can anyone help?

```css
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
  font-family: Folks;
  url(http://www.vtxfactory.com/Folks-Normal.ttf) format('truetype'),
}
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: Folks;
}
</style>
```

The font name is "Folks" but I'm only using "Folks-Normal" as I don't use the bold version. The font is already allocated on the directed url source.

You can see on http://www.vtxfactory.com/ that when you enter, font-family changes to Times New Roman and don't load my custom font.

Best Regards,
Rui Farinha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've missed required *src* property and semicolon at the end:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Folks;
  src: url('http://www.vtxfactory.com/Folks-Normal.ttf') format('truetype'); //<-- semicolon
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the url in the CSS to path

```
@font-face {
font-family: Folks;
src: url(/path/to/your/font/file/Folks-Normal.ttf) format('truetype'),
}
```

you can use this service too
http://www.font2web.com/